# Plot the phase portrait of a differential equation by using StreamPlot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, visualization

How can I plot phase portrait by using different initial conditions? Are these conditions already specified when I choose the min and max values in the StreamPlot command? I will post the equation once I try it by myself.
[Edit]
I am plotting the differential equation,
$$\ddot{\phi}+3\sqrt{\frac{8\pi G}{3}}\sqrt{0.5\dot{\phi^{2}}+0.5m^{2}\phi^2}+m^2\phi=0$$,
where G=1 and m=0.5.
I have also broken the equation down into system of two ODEs:
$$\dot\phi=y $$
and
$$\dot y= -3\sqrt{\frac{8\pi G}{3}}\sqrt{0.5y^2+0.5m^{2}\phi^2}-m^2\phi$$
I have plotted the results using the streamplot command but that wasn't right. So, I need to plot the phase portrait by using initial conditions. I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPoints.html.

Comment: It's hard to answer beyond that without a concrete example.

Comment: Can equation trekker be useful? for (phi,phidot) phase portrait ?

Comment: I've never used equation trekker, but it would really help if you gave an actual example for people to address.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have edited the question, and I have included the equation in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have plotted the results using the streamplot command but that
> wasn't right

It will help if you show what you tried, so one can see what the problem is and explain better why what you saw "wasn't right"

```
m = 1/2;
G = 1;
(*state space representation *)
x1d = x2
x2d = -3 Sqrt[8 Pi G/3] Sqrt[1/2 x2^2 + 1/2 m^2 x1^2] - m^2 x1;

ic = {1, 0};  (*maps to phi[0]==1, phi'[0]==0*)

StreamPlot[{x1d, x2d}, {x1, -1, 1.5}, {x2, -1, 1}, 
 StreamPoints -> {{{ic, Red}, Automatic}}, 
 StreamColorFunction -> None]
```

[image]

Change IC above to see different solution curves highlighted.

Compare to

```
ClearAll[phi, t]
ode = phi''[t] + 
    3 Sqrt[8 Pi G/3]*Sqrt[1/2 phi'[t]^2 + 1/2 m^2 phi[t]^2] + 
    m^2 phi[t] == 0;
ic = {phi[0] == 1, phi'[0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{ode, ic}, phi, {t, -0.2, 0.2}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{phi[t], phi'[t]} /. sol], {t, -0.2, 0.2}, AspectRatio -> 4]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, Nesser, I was getting the same plots, and the reason behind the wrong answer was a missing factor. The first term of the x2d must be multiplied by x2. It was my error.